Totally fanatic questions from US-Canada answered but others tagged as opinions. Racism stacking up for treatment?


I have a question about my Bitcoin Stack Exchange post: Without world denuclearization and privileged accepting transparency, can BItcoin have a future?

I've had a look at the linked question and see no indication that it was closed for any other reason than the cited speculative nature. If you see other questions that should be closed as primarily opinion-based, please feel free to flag them for review as well.
I've also removed your comment calling another contributor names for no reason.

The preacher is here defending his folks

As far as I can tell, all the issues I've looked into started at your end: You insinuated unfair behavior in others where there was none while being needlessly rude. Further, you followed another user around and harassed them. Now, you're getting in my face after no provocation by myself. This behavior is not acceptable. Either adhere to our "be nice" policy, or see yourself removed from this community. Thank you.
